# Unwanted duplicated activity

Tags: java, android

There is a code that sends an int 'a' from the main activity to activity B. It also starts activity B with the fade animations. However, this code creates 2 of the same activity B's and I only need 1 activity B. How can I fix this so that it only makes 1.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Handler splash = new Handler();
            int a = 1;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class));
            myIntent.putExtra("HEADER", a);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_switch_fast,R.anim.fade_out_switch_fast);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just remove this line from code:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class));
```

Rest is fine in your code.

Comment: but then it does no longer play the animation anymoreoverridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_switch_fast,R.anim.fade_out_switch_fast);

Comment: let it be there, and try to remove "startActivity(myIntent)"

Comment: int a = 1;
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("HEADER", a);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_switch_fast,R.anim.fade_out_switch_fast);
                finish(); Fixed it, it was the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the second activity twice. Remove the following line from your code and move `overridePendingTransition` after you use the intent to start the activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class));
```

Comment: But then it does not play my animation anymore :/

Comment: Did you move the `overridePendingTransition` below `startActivity(myIntent)`?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are starting Activity B twice!

you should remove this part of your code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class));
```

Comment: But then it no longer plays the animation between the two activities